# Mockito: How to test if another class' method is called within a method of a Mock?

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito, jboss-arquillian, verify

So I have a service class.

```
public class OrganisationService {
    public List<Organisation> findAllForeignOrganisations() {
        // a few rows of JPQL-code that searches the database
        return myCriteria.getResultList();
    }
    //...Other methods that return Lists with other types of organisations...
}
```

Then I have a class which I want to test. What I want to test is, when this following class's method `getAllowedOrganisations` is given certain parameter (`OrganisationType.FOREIGN` in this case), uses the aforementioned method findAllForeignOrganisation() to search for a List of organisations.

```
public class OrganisationSelectionOptions {

@Inject OrganisationService os;

public List<Organisation> getAllowedOrganisations(Assignment a) {
    OrganisationType type = a.getOrganisationType();
    return giveOrganisationListWithType(type);
}

private List<Organisation> giveOrganisationListWithType(OrganisationType type) {
    List<Organisation> organisations;
    if (type == OrganisationType.FOREIGN) {
        organisations = os.findAllForeignOrganisations();
    }
    // ...some other organisations types on if-clauses...
    return organisations;
    }
}

}
```

I made a JUnit test to test this. I have to create mocks of these aforementioned classes because they access database and currently I can't access the database in tests and would like to avoid implementing a database structure to tests.

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@PrepareForTest(Organisation.class)
public class OrganisationSelectionTest  {
    @Test
    public void testWithForeignType() throws RreflectionUtilException {
        // ...code to create a dummy Assignment with FOREIGN type   organisation...

    mockedOrganisationService = mock(OrganisationService.class);
    mockedOrganisationSelectionOptions = mock(OrganisationSelectionOptions.class);


    }
}
```

Now I tried Mockito's `verify` to somehow test, if `mockedOrganisationSelectionOptions.giveOrganisationListWithType(dummyAssignmentWithForeignTypeOrganisation)` would call `os.findAllForeignOrganisations();`  to no avail.

I'm a clueless beginner on creating tests. Any help would be vastly appreciated and rewarded, thank you.
I'm ready to answer any comments/questions to give more detail on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done via multiple ways but I will go over one.  First, because you use @Inject to get your instance of OrganisationService, then I will not mess around with mocking the `new OrganisationService()` constructor call.  Instead we can setup a getter method for the OrganisationService, then mock it.

Add a getter in OrganisationSelectionOptions .

```
OrganisationService getOrganisationService(){
    return os;
}
```

Edit your giveOrganisationListWithType method to use our new getter.

```
organisations = getOS().findAllForeignOrganisations();
```

In your unit test mock an instance of OrganisationService.  There are two ways to do this.

method one:  add the following in ToimeksiannonYhtiovalintaTest.

```
@Mock 
private OrganisationService mockOS;
```

method two:  instantiate your mockOS in the method doing the testing.

```
OrganisationService mockOS = mock(OrganisationService.class);
```

For method one to work you need to include..

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

in ToimeksiannonYhtiovalintaTest.  This is a class level annotation.

Next we need to spy the object being tested.

```
OrganisationSelectionOptions toTest = spy( new OrganisationSelectionOptions ());
```

then mock our new getter method.

```
when(toTest.getOrganisationService()).thenReturn(mockOS);
```

There you go.

EDIT:   added...

> Edit your giveOrganisationListWithType method to use our new getter.
>
> ```
> organisations = getOS().findAllForeignOrganisations();
> ```

Comment: Thank you, Jose. Your answer not only helped me with the issue but also demonstrated how to approach this type of testing. I'll green mark it as soon as I get to try it!